# How to Set the Environment variable based on the console output in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a python program using Jenkins "Build->Execute Shell" in a slave machine like below

cd tools/demo/
python3 test_client.py

On Executing-> i am getting output in the console like

```
+ python3 test_client.py
Received b'WAS03'
```

I would like to set the env variable with value as WAS03 (Whatever i ve received the output)

Comment: Is using a declarative Pipeline an option?

Comment: No. its a freestyle jenkins job

Answer (score 0):

Tried to redirect the output and grep the output and set the env variable in propertyfile
python3 test_client.py > output
setupName=`cat output | grep "setupName:" | awk '{print$2}'`
echo $setupName
echo SETUP_NAME=$setupName > propsfile

Used "Inject Environment Variable" plugin in Jenkins and passed the propertyfile
Then i am able to get the injected env variable in Pipeline